# How do I plot the graph for |x|+|y|=1 ranging from -1 to 1

Tags: matlab

What is the proper syntax for plotting the graph of |x|+|y|=1 ranging from -1 to 1.
Those are the absolute value of x and y, and I do not need to generate x and y. I am new to MATLAB and I simply do not understand how to do this.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's really just four different lines: x + y = 1, x - y = 1, -x + y = 1, -x - y = 1.

Comment: What about the absolute value? Don't I need to do abs(x) or something

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: That's not right. (-5,6) is part of your solution, but not of `|x|+|y|=1`

Comment: @Daniel How can (-5,6) be part of his solution, it just satisfies 1 equation, not the other 3.

Comment: @BedSheets This is what @Oli means. Run this code in MATLAB and see the square which is formed by the points where any two lines intersect. `x=-10:10;
y=-10:10; 
plot(1-y,y,'r-');
hold on;
plot(1+y,y,'g-');
hold on;
plot(y-1,y,'b-');
hold on;
plot(-y-1,y,'m-');` The square should be same as what you get in the answer below.

Comment: @Parag: No, you get a different solution.

Comment: @Daniel The square vertices match to the vertices of the square you get using `ezplot` function. I checked it manually.

Comment: @Parag: Compare your code with `ezplot('abs(x)+abs(y)=1',[-10 10],[-10 10])`, there is a difference but not in the [-1 1]x[-1 1]-range.

Comment: Yes, I get it. I meant the solution of the above 4 equations should be as same as `abs(x)+abs(y)=1`.

Answer (score 1):

The trickiest part is to find the right plotting function, i would use `ezplot`

```
ezplot('abs(x)+abs(y)=1',[-1 1],[-1 1])
```

Input should be obvious, function, x-range and y-range.

[image]

Comment: How would one do this with the new fplot, now that ezplot is deprecated?

Comment: Never used any of the recent Matlab versions, sorry but can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> t=-20:0.001:20;
>> y=1-t;
>> plot(t,y)
>> plot(t,y)
>> hold on
>> y=1+t;
>> plot(t,y)
>> hold on
>> y=-1+t;
>> plot(t,y)
>> hold on
>> y=-1-t;
>> plot(t,y)
>> hold on
>> axis([-1 1 -1 1])
```